# Create a data frame out of input_t (which is actually three numbers and act as features ) and output_t as output

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

This is my code

```
output_data = []
out = ''
i = 0
P = 500
X = 40000
while i<600:
    subVals = values[i:i+X]
    signal=subVals.val1
    signal, rpeaks = biosppy.signals.ecg.ecg(signal, show=False)[1:3]
    rpeaks=rpeaks.tolist()
    nni = tools.nn_intervals(rpeaks)
    fre = fd.welch_psd(nni)
    tm = td.nni_parameters(nni)
    f1=(fre['fft_peak'])
    t1=(tm['nni_min'])
    f11=np.asarray(f1)
    t11=np.asarray(t1)
    input_t=np.append(f11,t11)
    output_t=subVals.BLEEDING
    output_t=int(round(np.mean(output_t)))
    i+=P
```

As you see we are in a loop and the goal here is to create a data frame or a csv file from input_t and output_t. Here is an example of them in one loop

```
input_t
array([2.83203125e-02, 1.21093750e-01, 3.33984375e-01, 8.17000000e+02])
output_t
0
```

I am trying to create matrix where for every rows, the first three columns is one iteration of input_t and last column is output_t.  Based on the code, since i needs to be less than 600 and the initial value of i is 0 and the step is 600 so we have two loops which makes it 2 rows in total and 5 columns(4 values from input_t and 1 value from output_t) . I tried append, I tried something like out+="," but I am not sure why that is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Init any variable as a list before the loop and add results to it

```
out = []
while i<600:
    ....
    input_t=np.append(f11,t11)
    output_t=subVals.BLEEDING
    output_t=int(round(np.mean(output_t)))

    out.append(input_t+[output_t])
```

Now out is the list of lists which you can load to DataFrame

Comment: Thanks splash58. I am going to accept ur answer. That being said, for some reason, when I use out.append, it only shows numbers of input_t. Binary values of output_t are not added to the list

Comment: @NavidRashedi I don't know what value `output_t` gets  here `output_t=subVals.BLEEDING`. Maybe problem is here? because `out.append(input_t+[output_t])` does not calculate any value

Comment: Actually output_t is either 0 or 1. It is an integer number while input_t is an array.